# Как проверить значение переменной, если её может вообще не быть?

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

Недолго занимаюсь PHP. Есть  массив, который перебираю через foreach, и переменная `$tipCont`.

Нужно чтобы  переменная равнялась  точному значению video и существовала (в некоторых итерациях ассоциативного массива ее нету вообще). А если в цикле ее или нету или не равна значению чтобы прерывание было continue. По одному условию работает, по двум не понятно как в уроках php говорится про символы
|| AND и прочие. ну что-то они не работают.

```php
foreach($PostArray["response"]["items"] as $postsort ) {
  $tipCont = $postsort["attachments"][0]["type"]; 
  if ((!( $tipCont === 'video' )) || (empty($tipCont)))
    continue ;
```

Comment: Как переменная `$tipCont` зависит от массива? И если переменная пустая, то она по определению не может быть равна какому-то значению кроме пустой строки

Comment: а деньгами в магазине ты тоже так расплачиваешься - сначала пересчитываешь, а потом только смотришь, есть ли они у тебя? *какой смысл* проверять переменную на существование, если ты уже проверил её значение?

Comment: Переменная зависит, береться из этогоже массива при итерациях, просто я не весь код написал.Вопрос только в двух условиях как их объединить, поэтому посчитал что полный код не нужен.А если по одному условию то работает и данные вардампом выдаются .Вот полный код                         foreach($PostArray["response"]["items"] as $postsort ) {
 $tipCont = $postsort["attachments"][0]["type"];
       if ((!( $tipCont === 'video' ) ) || (empty($tipCont)))
      
        continue ;

Comment: Ну и САМОЕ ГЛАВНОЕ, что нужно знать всем тем, кто недолго занимается РНР: надо забыть слово "не работает". Когда ты общаешься с посторонними людьми, они понятия не имеют о том, что происходит у тебя на компьютере. Они не видят твоего экрана. И "не работает" не говорит им вообще ни о чём. писать надо **очень подробно:** что именно именно не работает и **как ты об этом узнал**

Comment: походу на непустоту надо проверить $postsort["attachments"], а не тип прикрепленного файла

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно проверять переменную не на пустоту, а есть ли вообще такой элемент в массиве, чтобы к нему обращаться. Для этого используется функция `isset()`

```php
foreach($PostArray["response"]["items"] as $postsort ) {
  if (isset($postsort["attachments"][0]["type"])) {
    $tipCont = $postsort["attachments"][0]["type"]; 
    if ($tipCont === 'video') {
      ....  // Process
    }
  }
}
```

Или, начиная с PHP 7.0 через оператор объединения

```php
foreach($PostArray["response"]["items"] as $postsort ) {
  $tipCont = $postsort["attachments"][0]["type"] ?? ""; 
  if ($tipCont === 'video') {
    ....  // Process
  }
}
```

Тогда если в массиве нет элемента `$postsort["attachments"][0]["type"]`, то `$tipCont` будет равен пустой строке

Comment: рекомендация так себе. сдвигать код метода на два блока вправо на пустом месте - далеко не лучшая идея. Особенно когда у человека изначально был правильный подход, с continue.

Comment: @Ипатьев Потом очень классно читать код, где эти `continue` размазаны ровным слоем по циклу. Или сидит где-то внутри тела цикла